# htaccess redirect url to directory file

Tags: php, .htaccess

am working on making my site urls search engine friendly and for which am rewriting urls with GET parameters  and so i have done rewriting but now htaccess is not pointing that url to php file which is suppose to handle the url

my old url

```
www.domain.com/foo/myfile.php?nid=554
```

new rewritten url with php

```
www.domain.com/foo/554-demo-page-title
```

my current htaccess rules   which work for old urls but not for new

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)-(.*) ./foo/myfile.php?nid=$1 [NC]
```

so i want to that both old and new urls land on /foo/myfile.php   becuase myfile.php can handle both urls incase of old url it rewrite and redirect as new url , i played for few hours with htaccess rules but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess (assuming there is `.htaccess` inside `foo/` directory):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^foo/(\d+)-.*$ foo/myfile.php [L,QSA,NC]
```

If you already have `/foo/.htaccess` then use this rule inside that file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /foo/

RewriteRule ^(\d+)-.*$ myfile.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: no there are no other htaccess rules ... your first htaccess rules set i added to site root htaccess file and your 2nd htaccess rules set i added to foo dir htaccess which i created new ,

Comment: ya with old url and adding garbage to foo dir .htaccess it throw 500 error

Comment: can you please check into it :: https://privnote.com/8Y3eai5U                open it with 123456789   , thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123886/discussion-between-anubhava-and-user889030).